# Serve Binary Content Using Clojure Ring

Tags: http, clojure, webserver

I wish to serve a PDF (or any other binary file) in a Clojure Ring response.  This works

```
(defn serve-file [request]
  {:status 200
   :headers {"Content-Type" "application/pdf"}
   :body (FileInputStream. "file.pdf")})
```

But I'm not explicitly closing the FileInputStream.  Will this cause a memory leak, or is it closed by the underlying web server (Jetty).  If not, how do I close it myself?

Comment: An alternative approach is to simply use `ring.middleware.file` and `file-info`. See http://mmcgrana.github.com/ring/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, ring does close the InputStream object passed in body key.

Check out : https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/ring-servlet/src/ring/util/servlet.clj#L111